# Fancybox 2: how to turn off loading graphic for img sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I tried adding $.fancybox.hideLoading() in the $(document).ready but I still see the image loading graphic for each image that loads in the auto play sequence.  Is there a way to suppress it? Note: using the Fancybox 2 API.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.fancybox.hideActivity();
});
```

From the [API Documentation](http://fancybox.net/api).

Comment: if you mean hideLoading(), it doesn't work.  I think because each image in the sequence is turning it back on.

Comment: I should add that I'm using fancybox 2, (hideActivity is not a method)

Comment: Well before downvoting me you should have specified that you were using Fancybox 2 - how could I have known that? My answer is correct for FB1.